# Connecting Vue.js Frontend -> through Express, Node.js, Sequelize (API) endpoints. (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, express, vue.js, sequelize.js

I have worked through various tutorials to understand and implement the Api Calls (Endpoints), defining Getters, almost to the point where I can fully invoke CRUD operations through routes pointing to them accordingly.

I can create Foreign Keys through sequelize, which creates my PostgreSQL table perfectly

```
async showAll (req, res) {
    try {
      const products = await Product.findAll({
        where: {}        
      })
      res.send(products)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An Error has occured trying to retrieve Products'
      })
    }
  },
```

In Postman 
When hitting my endpoint GET /principals
All the relevant products are also displayed

```
 {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Company B",
        "telephoneNumber": "012 111 1111",
        "address": "Betha Str\nBedrasDorp",
        "logo": "",
        "registrationNumber": "2020/123/1234",
        "taxNumber": "123",
        "monthEnd": 1,
        "createdAt": "2020-01-31T09:29:39.692Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-31T09:29:39.692Z",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 18,
                "stockCode": "U7U5U",
                "nappiCode": "NULL",
                "barCode": "NULL",
                "description": "Silver",
                "sysPrice": 297.43,
                "image": "",
                "createdAt": "2020-01-31T09:25:22.620Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-01-31T09:25:22.620Z",
                "principalId": 2
            },
```

My question
How do I display my Principal Name in a Vue component and not just the principalID as per sequelize created column on my postgreSQL DB.

My current  section within products.vue

```
<script>
....
async mounted () {
      // do request to list all products
      this.products = (await ProductsService.showAll()).data
  }
 ...
 </script>
```

displaying the productId

```
....
<template
  slot="items"
  slot-scope="{ item }">
  <td>{{ item.stockCode }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-left"> {{ item.principalId }} </td>
</template>
...
```

How can I display the Principal - name from a foreign key constraint? Linked in my PostgreSQL table in the Vue component.

Please help!

Comment: you can pass it (the main\parent object) too in the scope or even access it through this.$parent. the second way with $parent make the component less reusable as it relay on the parent to hold that info.

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it out.

You controller section should include.

```
async showAll (req, res) {
    try {
      const products = await Product.findAll({
        where: {},
        include: [
          {
            model: ParentName
          }
        ]        
      })        
      res.send(products)      
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An Error has occured trying to retrieve Products'
      })
    }
  }
```

Your .vue component Script section

```
    async mounted () {this.products = (await ProductsService.showAll()).data
  }
```

And calling it in the Template Component within vue becomes easy

```
{{ props.item.Principal.name }}
```

Comment: `{{ props.item.Principal.name }}` should be `{{ props.item.ParentName.name }}`